# Plesk Error - Failed domain creation - Serial Number update limit

Tags: dns, subdomain, plesk

I have an issue with my Plesk instance which really doesn't make sense to me.

I am creating a lot of subdomain for my clients on my main domain.
I don't handle any DNS on my server, service is disabled in Plesk and my 2 DNS servers for that main domain are my domain/vps provider ones *(OVH)*.

I use then to create a subdomain as a zone DNS for each of my client in OVH backend, but know I chose to simply use a wildcard to avoid having 100s of entry.

Then I go to plesk and add a subdomain *(vhost)* with the associated folder where the subdomain *(or domain)* needs to go. It use to work fine but unfortunately now I have an error saying:

> Error: Failed domain creation: Unable to update the domain data: The
>   serial number update limit was reached. No further change on the DNS
>   zone can be done today.

I really don't get it as, on my provider, I can create as many DNS zone as I want, and I really don't see the link between my server/Plesk vhosts/domains/subdomains and the DNS! I don't handle any DNS on my server and I thought creating a subdomain or domain on Plesk was just creating a vhost.

I am stuck on that one, would be great if any of you ever encounter that issue could help me.

**PS:** Couldn't find anything online ...

**PS2:** Called my provider and talked to me about SOA limitations, But again I can't see the link here. As the error is not when I try to create a DNS zone but when I try to set a new vhost.

Answer (score 1):

This is a plesk bug know for me as PPPM-2590.

As workaround you can uncheck 'Use serial number format recommended by IETF and RIPE' on parent domain where you have a lot of subdomains or server-wide in 'Tools & Settings > DNS Templates > SOA record Template' and sync template with domains.

You can try this custom fix

1. Make sure that you have latest update #68
2. Backup original file:

   cp /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Dns/Zone/Abstract.php /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Dns/Zone/Abstract.php.ORIG
3. Download https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B7Nx66lufdvpSkxxeHpqaGtvWTg&export=download and place it to /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Dns/Zone/Abstract.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did find that setting and thought it would work, but unfortunately I have the same error. I can't add more than 30 per day! this is crazy. I did your fix server wide so do I have do restart something or it should be automatic? I didn't to it just for that domain, because as I don't handle the DNS on my server, the per domain SOA config is grey (disabled)

Comment: I've updated answer with instruction how to apply fix on server. This fix allows any DNS operations even serial number update limit was reached.